# Laravel API Get method is working fine, Put,Delete,Post methods are not working on live server and with laragon pretty URL

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent, postman

Laravel API Get method is working fine, Put,Delete,Post methods are not working on live server and with laragon pretty URL.

When i add index.php with the url its work.
(eg:https://www.example.com/index.php/api/create-user)

what is the reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your .htaccess file.

If you correct the .htaccess file it will work without the need to add ...`index.php`

You can share your .htaccess of use the default one that comes with Laravel.